# Is it possible to count the number of tuples appears in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a count on the number of tuples that appear in a list.
like in below eg there are 4 tuples.

```
albums = [
    ("Welcome to my Nightmare", "Alice Cooper", 1975,
     [
         (1, "Welcome to my Nightmare"),
     ]
     ),
    ("Bad Company", "Bad Company", 1974,
     [
         (1, "Can't Get Enough"),
         (2, "Rock Steady"),

     ]
     ),
    ("Nightflight", "Budgie", 1981,
     [
         (1, "I Turned to Stone"),
     ]
     ),
    ("More Mayhem", "Imelda May", 2011,
     [
         (1, "Pulling the Rug"),
     ]
     ),
]
```

Comment: There are inner lists as well, which tuples do you want to count?

Comment: What's wrong with `len(albums)`?

Comment: For everyone thinking why to use `isinstance()`. [Visit This Page](https://switowski.com/blog/type-vs-isinstance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An efficient way would be:

```
sum(isinstance(x, tuple) for x in albums)
```

Docs on:

- [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)
- [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you count the number of tuples in a list.

```
if isinstance(albums, list):
    tuple_count = 0
    for tpl in albums:
        if isinstance(tpl, tuple):
            tuple_count  += 1
    print("Total tuples in albums list ", tuple_count)
```